# Airflow, Is there a way to provide metadata about a task that can be displayed on the console

Tags: python, airflow

I am using airflow to run a pipleine. Each task takes a Jar from a defined location and runs it. This location only contains the jar and so is inconvenient for any support tasks where a user needs to find the jar source code. Is it possible to display a link to the Jars source code repo somewhere on the airflow console. I know I could just include an echo command in the BashOperator but this seems a bit messy. Is there anyway to include the link in the task instance details for example?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. How many jar jobs are there? Please create an example about your structure and the idea you've got with the echo command. Also how are those jars used, what are those operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the `doc` or `doc_md` attribute on the `DAG` object to provide information that can be accessed via the UI. [More information is available here](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#documentation-notes).